# Magnetic fields and friction

Tags: electromagnetism, friction

If I was to pass a metal object through a magnetic field would there be any friction?

Comment: *Classical* friction is based on surface-contact.... so no.

Comment: Not friction, but there's Lenz's law. See here for a quick demo of the Lenz effect in action: https://youtube.com/watch?v=N7tIi71-AjA

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Friction is a force resisting relative movement of objects or fluids caused by the interactions taking place at the contact between the objects or fluids. Hence, by definition there cannot be friction between an object and magnetic field.

This does not mean though that there cannot be a force resisting movement of a metal object relative to magnetic field. You wouldn't call any such forces friction, though.

One kind of breaking force appears when a metal object moves relative to magnetic field and is caused by induction which produces [eddy currents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current) which in turn generate opposing magnetic field which resists the movement of the metal object. This is how [eddy current brake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current_brake) works.

Answer (score -3):

Not only a metal passed through a magnetic field will produce friction,  an  electron passed through a magnetic field produces heat due to friction.

Positive particles discharged from the sun enter our planet at the poles and as they pass through the earth's core they produce friction, this is what keep us at the current temperature.